# Audio runs very slow in IONIC based IOS App

Tags: ios, performance, ionic-framework, audio, buffer

I have created a Hybrid mobile app using Ionic framework, Cordova and Angular. It has functionality of running Audio on this App. I'm using native audio for playing audios from remote server. The problem we are facing now is , Android app runs the Audio very fast. But there is almost 10secs buffer on iOS before audio starts playing .Can you suggest some solution to this problem?

Comment: It's depends device RAM. Test the application same size of ram in both android, iOS.

Comment: In ios in oerformance it is always be faster then android and thus the results should be reversed. But since the ios is taking 10 sec request, then it is either the http request itself may take delay maybe for ios security reasons to check file source or the audio plugin itself causing the file delay. In order to be sur, try to use the audio plugin for playing a file from inside the assets and see if it shows also a 10 sec buffer if it is not from remote server.